# How can I re-use PHP configuration directives in multiple Nginx server blocks?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

So I have Nginx & php-fpm serving multiple sites on different domains. The configuration file gets very large due to the repetition of `location ~ \.php$ { }` blocks in each `server { }` block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name firstsite.com;
    root /var/www/firstsite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/firstsite;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name secondsite.com;
    root /var/www/secondsite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/secondsite;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I can't move the blocks off to another file and include it, as `root` changes in each instance. How can I avoid all that repetition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You move the common stuff off to another file and `include` it.

Comment: Yes, but the point here is the "root" directive is different for each block. If I could pass variables with each include statement, that'd be great.... but you can't afaik

Comment: Nobody said anything about putting `root` in. It's not common to all your configuration blocks!

Comment: Soerry, perhaps I wasn't explaining myself very well. Each location { } block has a root directive in. It's just it's value changes for each instance. ....so it's how I'd get round that without having to repeat each block.

Comment: Well, you can always remove them... they shouldn't be there anyway.

Comment: God you're right as well. They can go in the main server {} block.... Sorry, I'm not normally this dumb honestly

Answer (score 3):

Create a directory such as `/etc/nginx/package-configs/` and put the common php stuff into file `/etc/nginx/package-configs/php.conf`.

To use the file, in your php locations put `include /etc/nginx/package-configs/php.conf`.

Comment: So I'd still have to start that location ~ \.php$ { } block in the main server block, then include another file inside it that has all parameters other than the root one? That gets the amount of lines down a bit I suppose, even if it isn't ideal....

Answer (score 3):

For a more generic answer, you can also use a template:

```
# conf.d/sites.conf
server { 
  set $sitename brazzers.com
  include conf.d/site.template;
}
server { 
  set $sitename playboy.com
  include conf.d/site.template;
}
```

```
# site.template
location / {
        root /var/www/$sitename;
        # etc etc etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't realize the `set` directive could be so useful. Is it possible to `set $variable` to be nothing at all? I'm trying to further reduce the number of template files by using a `$subdomain` variable, e.g. `server_name $subdomain$sitename;`, if I understand this correctly.